# Retrieving specific columns sum from Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, filter, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

I have data with several columns in the same table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
```

I want to retrieve the sum from Col1 to Col3, from Col3 to Col6, or from Col1 to Col6 from table, however I can't figure out how to  select these specific columns.

Comment: Can you show sample data, desired results, and how you will be deciding whether you want 1-3, 3-6, or 1-6?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.col_sums_from_some_table
AS
  SELECT 
     [Col1-3] = Col1 + Col2 + Col3,
     [Col3-6] = Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6,
     [Col1-6] = Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6
  FROM dbo.table_name;
```

(You'll need to wrap those with `COALESCE` as @davek pointed out if these columns are nullable.)

Then you can simply select the column you're after directly or applying SUM():

```
SELECT [Col1-3] FROM dbo.col_sums_from_some_table;

SELECT SUM([Col1-6] FROM dbo.col_sums_from_some_table;
```

You could also create computed columns on the table, e.g. (and I'm guessing on data type here):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name ADD [Col1-3] 
  AS CONVERT(INT, COALESCE(Col1, 0) + COALESCE(Col2, 0) + COALESCE(Col3, 0));
```

And you could choose to persist / index these computed columns as well.

Comment: Thanks Aaron :) well years are 2007 2008 2009 2010 as column which have sales data which i want to select specific years..... i will pass parameter to the stored procdure and based on it i will decide in the where condition which feild to select ps: i connected these columns with numbers so i would know that column 1 =1997 column2 =1998 if i want to say column 1-5 or column 2-6 ... any advise

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, as I asked for before. Right now this might be accomplished with a pivot, or it might require dynamic SQL. Having a more explicit understanding of what you're trying to do (without introducing word problems) will make it easier to help you solve the problem. Please read: http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: Thank Aaron :) well you have table of data of several months and you want to select a certain period ........ the end result you want to  select sum(month1+month2) or select sum(month1+month2+month3) or select sum(month2+month3+month4) Data would look like this : X1 (month1+month2 Total)=30 ....etc

Comment: @user1691071 please update your question. Nobody is going to read "data" posted in a comment.

Comment: i  just cant figure out what is the syntax of  selection certain period from a table.... note that you understood me perfectly and gave me a useful solution in the create view thing.............. appreciated your help

Answer (score 1):

For a single row:

```
select col1 + col2 + col3 from mytable
```

(assuming all columns are numeric)

For summing all values for a particular column:

```
declare @sum int
set @sum = 0

select @sum = @sum + col1 from mytable
```

Summing all rows for e.g. columns 1 and 2:

```
declare @sum int
set @sum = 0

select @sum = @sum + col1 + col2 from mytable
```

To deal with nulls effectively, you can use the coalesce function:

```
declare @sum int
set @sum = 0

select @sum = @sum + coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) from mytable
```